# Problema c++ retiro de letra en cadena

Tags: c++

Hola tengo el siguiente problema, quiero retirar una letra de mi codigo y quisiera saber por que el codigo no me anda

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

string remover_caracter(char *nombre, char letra);

int main()
{
    char nombre[] = "recurrente";
    char letra;

    cin >> letra;

    cout << remover_caracter(nombre, letra) << endl;

    return 0;
}

string remover_caracter(char *nombre,char letra)
{
    int longitud = strlen(nombre);
    char total[] = "";

    string palabraFinal="";

        for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
        {
            int contador=0;

            if (nombre[i] == letra)
            {
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                total[contador] = nombre[i];
                contador++;
            }
        }


    return total;
}
```

como resultado me sale cualquier cosa, quisiera saber en que parte del codigo estoy fallando y como puedo hacer para solucionarlo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas fallando aquí:

```
char total[] = "";
```

Ahí, estás creando una cadena vacía; es decir, una cadena con espacio para **1 solo elemento**: el `\0` que marca el final de la misma.

Ya que creas una variable de tipo `string` ... ¿ Porqué no la usas ?

```
string remover_caracter( char *nombre, char letra ) {
    int longitud = strlen( nombre );
    string palabraFinal;

    for( int i = 0; i < longitud; ++i ) {
        if( nombre[i] != letra ) { palabraFinal.push_back( nombre[i] ); }
    }

    return palabraFinal;
}
```